# Neo4j granular data access control

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently working with a neo4j graph that looks something like this:
[image]

I want to data access controls so that different users only have access to certain subgraphs.
For example, **User A** will only have read access to Category node <18 and the nodes that are downstream of that node:
[image]

**User B** will only have read access to Category node 18-25 **AND** category node 25-35 and its downstream nodes.
[image]

Is it possible to create cypher queries that will be this granular? From Neo4j documentation, to me it looks like I can get set read access at the *node label* level and not specific nodes within a given label.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is definitely possible to define queries like that. If you want to do this at application level, you could also use an approach as illustrated here : https://youtu.be/HsTTjpc9xks

Disclosure : I work for Graphileon.